# How to print List<grid> on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've got two pages in windows phone project:

### MainPage.xaml

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                 <StackPanel x:Name="stp" Orientation="Horizontal"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>
    </Grid>
```

### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void gotoAddPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AddPage.xaml",
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    (App.Current as App).todoList.ForEach(delegate(Grid g)
    {
        stp.Children.Add(g);
    });

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

### AddPage.xaml.cs

```
    private void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
        Grid gr = new Grid();
        gr.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
        gr.ShowGridLines = true;

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = addTxtbox.Text;
        gr.Children.Add(tb);
        (App.Current as App).todoList.Add(gr);

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

I am using App as storage for List.
The problem is when I am trying to add list items to stack panel on the MainPage it creates an exception (Element is already the child of another element.) after I add the 2nd item in the list (on the AddPage) and return back to MainPage and try to print it.

Comment: This is a good illustration of why to use data binding ...

Comment: This is just some kind of exercise for myself, but I am wondering why I've got such an error.

Comment: The reason is that a given object can only be added once to the visual tree.  You can't add the `todoList` children to some other parent without first removing them.

Comment: Oooh, now it works (I have just use the Clear() function in stackpanel while NavigatingFrom). Thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool ... maybe post your answer and self-accept?